# Mouse Click event picturebox visual c

Tags: visual-c++

I have the following problem:

I've created a picture box on a dialog box by using the common tool in Visual Studio. In this box I show a picture that has been chosen by the user through some code.

Now, I need to get the position of a Mouse Click (left button) inside this picture box.

I tried the STN_CLICKED (with the NOTIFY property = true) but it not what I need.

Can you solve this problem ? (Note visual C++)

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you already tried?

Comment: Thanks duDe! I'm new at visual c++ so I have no other idea. Can you help me?

Comment: Have added an answer, take a look ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, add instead OnLButtonDown event of a parent dialog, NOT of a PictureControl!

```
afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(
   UINT nFlags,
   CPoint point 
);
```

Here you have already needed coordinates (point).

Comment: Can you explain the steps to do it? Excuse me, but I'm new to Visual C++

Comment: My problem is: the user click on a button, then the program need the user click on a point inside the picturebox because it has to color some pixels around this position.

Answer (score 0):

first open your Myform.h[design] i.e your UI part. click on your picture box. it will redirect you to `pictureBox1_Click` function. there you can use this  `mouseEventArgs` to get the location of mouse pointer on mouse click.

```
private: System::Void pictureBox1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

                 MouseEventArgs ^ms = (MouseEventArgs^)e;
                 int X = ms->X;
                 int Y = ms->Y;
}
```